# Building non-java project

Tags: maven-2

I'm trying to build non-java project, it basically has some folders and subfolders I want to include in the jar is that possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. It's trivial if you use the standard layout (put your stuff inside `src/main/resources`), otherwise you just have to [specify resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html):

```
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>some/directory</directory>
            <targetPath>first</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>some/other/directory</directory>
            <targetPath>second</targetPath>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>a/third/directory</directory>
            <!-- standard target path -->
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

<s>You should probably also set the property `<maven.test.skip>true</maven.test.skip>`</s>. Nope, just checked, you don't need to.

Basically, some participants of the standard workflow (namely the compiler and the surefire plugin) check for java source folders, and if they don't find any, they just skip processing.